# Does this code gives me confidence intervals? 95%

Tags: r, glm, confidence-interval

I am running logistic regression and want to be sure that I am getting 95% conficence intervals. Code:

```
# Dissable scientific notation. 
# From: stackoverflow.com/questions/25946047
options(scipen=999)



###############################################################################


OR_CI_round_number<-5  # How many decimal point to keep after rounding OR and CI.


dfAPI <- haven::read_dta(
  file = "https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/eyestudy.dta") 


dfAPI$carrot<-factor(dfAPI$carrot)
dfAPI$carrot<-relevel(dfAPI$carrot, ref = "1")


glmAPI = glm(lenses ~ carrot, data= dfAPI, family=(binomial(link = "log")))
#glmAPI
#summary(glmAPI)
round(exp(cbind(RR = coef(glmAPI), confint(glmAPI))), OR_CI_round_number)
round(exp(cbind(RR = coef(glmAPI), confint(glmAPI, level = 0.95))), OR_CI_round_number)
```

Result:

```
> round(exp(cbind(RR = coef(glmAPI), confint(glmAPI, level = 0.95))), OR_CI_round_number)
Waiting for profiling to be done...
                 RR   2.5 %  97.5 %
(Intercept) 0.41176 0.28349 0.54870
carrot0     1.58601 1.09250 2.40172

> round(exp(cbind(RR = coef(glmAPI), confint(glmAPI))), OR_CI_round_number)
Waiting for profiling to be done...
                 RR   2.5 %  97.5 %
(Intercept) 0.41176 0.28349 0.54870
carrot0     1.58601 1.09250 2.40172
```

The reason that I am asking is because I am getting `RR   2.5 %  97.5 %`. As I understand they indicate upper and lower boundaries of 95% Confidence intervals. Is this correct?

Comment: Please also edit to only include the relevant packages. It seems only one is required for `read_dta`. Negates the need to download packages first.

Comment: See `help(confint)`. To answer the question, yes, the default is 95% (this is shown in the help page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, correct, those are your boundaries and areas to the left of 2.5% and to the right of 97.5% are significance levels.